# Undefined index:test in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

in Code Igniter i have declared some constants in constatnts.php like this

```
define('TEST',$_REQUEST['test']);
```

but they are not working and showing the error like  `Notice: Undefined index: testin C:\xampp\htdocs\userinterface\application\config\constants.php on line 39`

what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that the superglobal `$_REQUEST` does not have an item with the index of `'test'`.

In other words, `isset($_REQUEST['TEST'] === FALSE`

You need to test that it **is set** before trying to use it to define the constant.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['TEST']))
{
  define('TEST',$_REQUEST['test']);
}
```

In this case, because the constant may not get defined, you always need to make sure it exists before you use it.

```
if(defined("TEST"))
{
  echo TEST;
}
```